# The latest commit gone after hard reset

Tags: git

I commited my changes and didn't push them to the server. Then I did hard reset to one of my previous commits and my latest commit gone. Does it mean commits which weren't pushed to server gone after hard reset?

edit: 
Is it possible to recover my latest commit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but not immediately.
Reflog entries will expire in time and the contents *will* disappear on garbage collection.

You can still get them back from the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

and reset to them/checkout:

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

or, e.g. checking it out to a *rescue* branch:

```
git checkout -b rescue HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: You are a life savior!