# Any way I can restore all my lost local work which was destroyed using GitHub?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I'm doing some work with Xcode, using local git first.
In order to share the code, I started trying GitHub.
Somehow, I made a mess.

Today, after the code was working to some extent, I actives GitHub to upload the code.
Then I found that I have nothing locally left.

I had all my code in User/Developer and 3 nights work is gone :(

Anyway that I can restore my code?

Comment: Did you check your git reflog? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778/6309 )

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! I haven't tried that yet. Right now, if I go to Xcode, I can no longer see in repository all my history. It now shows the one synched from GitHub master branch(which has nothing there). And I've lost all my code :(  Following instructions in the link you pointed just now, will it get both my files back and the history?

Comment: If you have committed locally, then you can restore that old SHA1. But any non-committed work is likely lost (unless you have the time machine - like in http://www.macworld.com/article/1164963/mac_basics_how_to_set_up_time_machine.html - activated on that drive)

Comment: Hi, I don't have time machine set up. But I did committed all my local changes before I was using GitHub. I'lll google a bit where/how git stores initial revisions and changes, and how to restore them. Thanks, VonC!

Comment: ok I have put together an answer highlighting the two common cases where data can "disappear" and how to get the right commit back in the working tree.

Comment: XCode uses AutoSave but doesn't offer a menu item to revert to previous versions. If you open the files in TextEdit, you can do File > Revert and even see the whole AutoSave history.

Answer (score 1):

If you have, as you comment, commit your changes before seeing them gone when activating GitHub link within XCode, then you should be able to restore those commits:

[`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is the way to look at *all* commits, including the one no longer referenced.
See for instance "[The latest commit gone after hard reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443327/the-latest-commit-gone-after-hard-reset)".

[`git branch -a`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) can also show you the current branch and help you see if you need to checkout your first branch back.
This kind of scenario happens when a remote branch (still empty) is accidentally checked out: see "[can git checkout be undone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912040/6309)".
If that was the case (ie, if XCode mistakenly checked out a remote empty branch), you can easily go back to the branch you were with:

```
git checkout -
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try it immediately when I get back home tonight.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see all my history. but when I tried "git checkout -" it showed: Ruian:RpnCalculator Ruian$ git checkout -
.gitignore: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first

Comment: okay... I think I did the most unprofessional thing I ever did. Just tired "$ git reset --hard HEAD" and seems I really lose everything now :( My bad...

Comment: @RAX so no commit before that reset? Because if there were commits, they are in the reflog.

Comment: yes... I saw the commits before I blindly did "git reset-hard HEAD". Now there's no history :( sorry, my bad...

Comment: @RAX but that's my point: if there *were* commits, a `git reset --hard` won't delete them (simply hide them in the reflog)

Comment: Hi, VonC, sorry that I'm replying late. I was on my way for a business trip and just arrived yesterday in China. I'll be able to check and update later tonight. Thanks for your help!